# how to use composite association key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I use foreign keys for associated models, but get names conflict

models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :status
end

class Poll < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :status_poll
end

class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end

class StatusPoll < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :polls
end
```

schema:

```
create_table "polls", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "title"
t.integer  "status_poll_id", default: 0
end

create_table "status_polls", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "title"
end

create_table "statuses", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "title"
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer  "status_id",              default: 0
t.string   "name"
end
```

i try popoulate polls via lib/tasks/data.rake:

```
namespace :data do
  task :populate_polls => [:populate_users, :populate_status_polls] do   
    users = User.all.where(status_id: [1, 2])

    users.each do |user|
      polls_quantity = rand(7..21)
      polls_quantity.times do |n|
        Poll.create!(   
          title: Faker::Name.title + '_' + user.id.to_s + '_' + n.to_s,
          user_id: user.id,
          status_poll_id: rand(0..1),
          description: Faker::Lorem.paragraph(7)
        )
      end  
    end
  end 
end
```

after run populate console display follow error message:

> kalinin@kalinin ~/rails/phs $ rake data:populate_polls rake aborted!
>   ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::UniqueViolation: ОШИБКА: 
>   повторяющееся значение ключа нарушает ограничение уникальности
>   "statuses_pkey" DETAIL:  Ключ "(id)=(0)" уже существует. : INSERT INTO
>   "statuses" ("id", "title") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"

but i not use statuses. i use status_poll_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is this: INSERT INTO "statuses" ("id", "title") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"

It's telling you it's attempting to insert a record into statuses that already exists. This likely happens in one of the sub-tasks or perhaps a sub-task of those.

In short, determine where records are inserted into statuses and figure out why it's attempting to insert duplicate records.